# Lost Windows 10 during installation of Ubuntu 17.10 for UEFI

Tags: dual-boot

I wanted to install Ubuntu 17.10 alongside Windows 10. But it all got messed up while I was installing Ubuntu 17.10!

The problem is UEFI mode. I don't know UEFI. I still want to dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10, So what can I do now?

Note: My laptop is Asuspro core i7 2.4 ghz processors, 8GB ddr3 ram, and entering the BIOS I didn't find so called UEFI!

I tried from Windows 10 **Control Panel > Recovery** but didn't find UEFI Firmware settings. How can I find it to configure?

Comment: Some MFG. may still use BIOS as that is the term users understood, and then it really is UEFI. But Windows requires vendors to use UEFI with gpt partitioning for all pre-installed systems since Windows 8 was released. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
Many Asus need this pci=nomsi
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303665

Answer (score -2):

had same issue dual boot, and they say boot livecd and install something,
but I found it so easy livecd - install grub-customizer and use the
"write to mbr" option. reboot and all fixed.

Clonezilla saves original mbr and can use linux dd command to put it back or clonezilla itself will put it back for you. But am not skilled at most clonezilla options.